# Jquery events, simple clicks, how and why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

So i have some data on a page (a table) which based on some options elsewhere may get ajax reloaded from the server.
This table has buttons in it that can be clicked to make other things happen to the records in the table.

I notice that this ...
   http://api.jquery.com/on/
... is the recommended approach for attaching simple event handlers to elements but that only attaches to elements that exist right now, and when I do my ajax load I lose the attached handlers.

So I started using this ... http://api.jquery.com/live/ ... and guess what, jquery team did their usual and deprecated it saying I should be using "on".

These functions behave very differently yet jquery docs say i should be using them interchangably so ...

Can someone explain the "on" equivelent of this and how I can get it to work with elements after an ajax call replacing the elements that hae previously been attached to ...

```
 $("some selector").live('click', function (e) {
            // some code code
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
```

My understanding is that you would do something like ...

```
 $("some selector").on('click', function (e) {
            // some code code
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
```

My guess is that I then have to re-run this code after performing my ajax call by putting this in to some sort of "initClicks" function and calling it both on page load and after the ajax call.

This seems to be a bit of a back step to me ... or have i missed something here?

Comment: read up on 'event delegation'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.on('click', function (e) {})` function, it works only for existing elements.
To handle click event on all `selector` elements, even for elements which will be added in future, you can use one of these functions:

```
$(document).on('click', "some selector", function (e) {
    // some code code
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

or:

```
$("body").delegate("a", "click", function () {
    // your code goes here
});
```

For more information read article about [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: having reread the documentation on this i now feel like such a spanner ... its obvious now !!

Answer (score 3):

Since the elements are added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', 'some selector', function(event) {
    // some code code
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; 
});
```

Also, either use [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false`, as:

```
return false = e.preventDefault() + e.stopPropagation()
```

So, there is no need to use both of them at same time.

Comment: good catch on the return code by the way, i tend to only use return false but this code is something i picked up from a colleague so has both.

Answer (score 1):

`live()` is not magic, it cannot see future elements, what it was doing is to attach a listener to the first root element of your page `document` and checks every bubbled event if it match your target selector, and when it find a match, it executes your function.

this is called [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

`live()` has been deprecated for good reasons, mainly the performance hit caused by using it.

then the jQUery team introduced the `delegate()` function which gave us a new way to achieve the exact result, but it has addressed the performance hit very cleverly by limiting the scope in which it will listen to bubbled events to the possible nearest parent of your now & future elements.

when they introduced the `On()` function, they gave you the ability to use it as normal event handler, or as a delegated handler for future elements.

so I believe they did a good job for this, giving us the flexibility to use it as we wish according to the specific scenario.

**Code Examples:**

using `delegate()`:

```
$( "#TAGERT_ID" ).delegate( "a", "click", function() { // your code goes here}
```

using `on()` (for delegated events)

```
$( "#TAGERT_ID" ).on( "click", "a", function() { // your code goes here}
```

both ways are the same, and will handle future clicks on `a` which will be added in the future inside your `TARGET_ID` element.

`TARGET_ID` is an example for using ID for your selector, but you can use whatever selector according to your specific need.

Comment: Yeh i think the cause of my confusion is that on and off wernt around when I was using live and i'm pretty sure that when they first introduced them they still didn't support this delegation approach. It's good that they have it now but it does confuse me that the jquery team change so much so often.

Comment: I hope that it's now more clear for you, and hope that I could help a little clarifying it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of said `live` is

```
$(document).on('click', "some selector", function (e) {
    // some code code
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

The [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) is a single stop for all event handler formats, the model you used is the same as

```
$("some selector").click(function (e) {
    // some code code
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

which does work based event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

You can never actually attach event listener to an element which does not exist in DOM yet. What `live` and `on` method do is attach listener on a parent which exists right now. `live` is nothing but an `on` attached on `document` itself.

Comment: Live is essentially doing that by saying "if i ever get something that matches this selector, do this with it ...". Nothing stops me doing this "in case an element exists in the future", in such a scenario I am potentially setting up event handlers for elements that don't yet exist. I don't disagree with you but in a sense I kind of don't agree with you either. lol.